# Manipulating strings from a file

Tags: java, string, file

I have a file with a syntax that looks like this:

```
! <Group>, Column1, column2, column3 
Group, 10, 20, 30
Group, 11, 12, 13
...
! <AnotherGroup>, Column1, column2, column3, column4
AnotherGroup, 10, 20, 30, A
AnotherGroup, 11, 12, 13, B
...
```

When I try to manipulate the strings through the Scanner object, some strange things are happening such as:

- end of file is found
- sometimes does not recognize the character "!" (see code snippet)
- sometimes does not recognize space characters

  ```
      sc = new Scanner(new File("files/myFile"));
  while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
      String tempLine = sc.nextLine();
      if (tempLine.contains("!")) {
          System.out.println(tempLine);
  ```

Anyway, I think I have to read the entire file and stores it in a specific format in order to manipulate.

Any advices?

**Edited after first answer:
This is the case wich sometimes does not recognize the character "!" (see code snippet)**

My Sysout:

```
! <Group1>, Column1, column2, column3 
! <Group2>, Column1, column2, column3 
! <Group5>, Column1, column2, column3
```

Didnt read the lines with groups 3 and 4

Comment: Why don't you give [BufferedReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) a try.

Comment: `sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile")));` I have tried, happens the same way.

Comment: A suggested change: `if (tempLine.startsWith("!")) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that there is a problem with the Scanner. At least the part of the code that you have provided should work fine.
May be verify if you are doing some silly mistake or wait until some gurus come to your help ;-)

Comment: I, too, do not see any problems with his provided Scanner code

Comment: Your code works totally fine and "as expected" for me. Can you attach your whole code.

Comment: I dont believe the problem is in code, but in the file. Because of this I asked if I need to convert the file to something, before manipulate it.

Comment: probably the lines in your file do not end with System.getProperty("line.separator")

Comment: How were you reading two lines at a time? Is the code you are actually using not like the code you posted here? Also, instead of marking as correct an answer that says "Looks good, make sure you're not doing anything silly" you should probably create your own answer to your question which explains your results and accept that. The accepted answer is supposed to be something that other people can look at later and see how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how the scanner works. nextLine() causes the scanner to skip over the rest of the current line it is looking at, and it returns a String containing the text that was skipped. It leaves the scanner at the beginning of the next line.

You did not explain the context of when your strange things happen. When you say "end of file is found" is one of your strange things that is happening, I will assume this happens near the end when you would expect one more line to be processed. If the scanner is looking at the beginning of the last line in the file, what is hasNextLine() going to return? Your while loop is going to be finished without processing some of your file's contents. If this is not the behavior you are experiencing, you need to explain better.

If you want to use a scanner, try checking out something like [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html).